# How to decode the OpenLR string in a HERE Traffic API v7 response?

Tags: here-api

I'm currently building a client that requests Traffic Flow data from the Traffic API v7:

`https://data.traffic.hereapi.com/v7/flow?locationReferencing=olr&…`

I would like to decode the [OpenLR Location Referencing](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic-api/dev_guide/topics/concepts/location-referencing.html) string contained in the response, but I'm not using Java nor Scala so I cannot use the libraries provided.

Returned strings look like this:

`"olr": "CCoBEAAmJQm+WSVVfAAJBQQCAxoACgUEAogZAAHtA2UACQUEAgOEADBigj0="`

I've read the [paragraph](https://developer.here.com/documentation/location-library/dev_guide/docs/location-referencing-olr.html) on the difference between TISA OLR and TomTom OpenLR, and I am able to find [online decoders](https://demo.tomtom.com) for the TomTom OpenLR strings as well as some [libraries](https://github.com/tomtom-international/openlr) in various languages; but none of those work for the OpenLR string that the HERE API returns.

Are there any resources (source code, online decoders, further documentation) that have details on decoding OpenLR strings used by HERE?

Answer (score 2):

HERE Location Lib would do it for you.

```
import com.here.platform.location.referencing.olr.OlrPrettyPrinter;
import com.here.platform.location.tpeg2.BinaryMarshallers;
import com.here.platform.location.tpeg2.olr.LinearLocationReference;
import com.here.platform.location.tpeg2.olr.OpenLRLocationReference;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.Base64;
public class decode {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode("CCoBEAAmJQm+WSVVfAAJBQQCAxoACgUEAogZAAHtA2UACQUEAgOEADBigj0=");
        OpenLRLocationReference reference =
                BinaryMarshallers.openLRLocationReference()
                        .unmarshall(new ByteArrayInputStream(decode));
        System.out.println(OlrPrettyPrinter.prettyPrint((LinearLocationReference) reference.getLocationReference()));
    }
}
```

output below:

```
type: OLR LinearLocationReference
    positiveOffset: DistanceMetresMax15000(98)
    negativeOffset: DistanceMetresMax15000(317)
    firstReferencePoint:
        coordinate: 2446716,638553 => 52.50083,13.701861
        lineProperties:
            bearing: 26 => 36.6°
            frc: 2 (0-7, with 0 most important)
            fow: 3 => single carriageway
        pathProperties:
            lfrcnp: 2 (0-7, with 0 most important)
            dnp: 1049 m
            againstDrivingDirection: false
    intermediateReferencePoints: ∅
    lastReferencePoint:
        coordinate: 869,493 => 52.50952,13.706791
        lineProperties:
            bearing: 132 => 185.6°
            frc: 2 [0-7], with 0 most important
            fow: 3 => single carriageway
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution in Java and especially for sharing the readable contents of the encoded string; but as I mentioned I'm not using Java. Are there implementations in languages other than Java/Scala out there?

Comment: Hi @mattsches, unfortunately, it supports Java/Scala only at this moment.

Comment: Hi @HEREDeveloperSupport, is it only possible to decode the messages by using your location library and not the standard binary data format specification? The documentation makes it seem as if it's possible to decode "manually" but the message doesn't conform to the standard as far as I can tell. It would be nice if you could add information on how to decode it at the bit level, or at least how it differs from the publicly available specification in the 2012 whitepaper. Right now there is only a link to the ISO standard, which doesn't contain any further binary message specification.

Comment: There is an OpenLR Whitepaper which describes the binary version 3 at bit level and also a demo tool:
https://demo.tomtom.com/
Unfortunately there are mistakes and missing parts in the Whitepaper and mistakes in the calculations of the demo tool. The whitepaper seems deprecated. For more informations about the specific differences you can hit me up, I am also at it.